# Careers Searches Statistic

Tags: discussion

On the careers page near the bottom it gives you some statistics one of these is searches and currently reads 14. What does this mean? Is it the total amount of searches employers have done? Or the amount of search results my CV has appeared on?

Thanks

Comment: Pictures speak louder than words!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently it reads 14 for everybody since it's the total searches done in the system. CV Search hits is how many searches have had you as one of the result.